# Degree of the field extension $K(x)\hookrightarrow\operatorname{Quot}\left(K[x,y]/(f)\right) $

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, extension-field

> Let $K$ be a field, and $f\in K[x,y]$ an irreducible degree $d$ polynomial. I want to prove that the field extension
>   $$
> K(x)\hookrightarrow \operatorname{Quot}\left(K[x,y]/(f)\right)
> $$
>   has degree $d$, where $\operatorname{Quot}\left(K[x,y]/(f)\right)$ is the quotient field of the ring $K[x,y]/(f)$.

Is it true? I don't know where to start. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: What means "a degree $d$ polynomial"? For instance, $f=X^3-Y^2$ has total degree $3$ and $K(X)\subset Q(K[X,Y]/(f))=K(\sqrt X)$ has degree $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've proved [in this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1396401/fraction-field-of-fx-yf-isomorphic-to-fxy-f/1396414#1396414) that the field of fractions of $K[X,Y](f)$ is $K(X)[Y]/(f)$, so $[K(X)[Y]/(f):K(X)]=\deg_Yf$.